# Logging with runtime modifications

Tags: vb.net, logging, nlog

I'm an inexperienced VB.NET programmer trying to add logging to his application.  I'm using Nlog and it works well but I need my user to be able to select the log level (Debug, Info, Warn) they wish to see and toggle logging to a file via config page at runtime.

Nlog is working well with a static configuration in app.config but changing rules programatically at runtime is where I'm struggling.  I've read the API documentation and there are ways to "Add" targets or rules, but I can see o easy way to "Remove" a target or modify a rule.

I've also looked at a Facade like SLF to try and make my life simpler, but I also don't see an easy way to add new logging targets or change the log level at runtime.

Any advice, code snippets (I'm good with VB or C#) would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules and enable or disable logging for a certain level. For instance, using a small project with an NLog config as :

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <targets>    
    <target name="console" xsi:type="Console" layout="${message}"/>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="console" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

and a console app like

```
Sub Main()

    Dim log As Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger

    REM Both lines will be logged as defined in the NLog.config 
    log.Debug("debug message")
    log.Info("info message")

    For Each rule As LoggingRule In LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules
        rule.DisableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
        REM rule.EnableLoggingForLevel(LogLevel.Debug)
    Next

    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()

    REM This line will not be logged as we just disabled it
    log.Debug("debug message")
    REM This line will still be logged
    log.Info("info message")

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

will disable all logging for level debug and below. Quite crucial is the line:

```
LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers()
```

I hope this helps.